# How to use TypeScript and import statements without systemJS or bundling JS?

Tags: javascript, typescript

If I code any TypeScript stuff and use import statements, the imports are transpiled to require-statements.
Because require isn´t according to ECMA, I have to use systemJS.
I import other code like classes, helpers or something like that. Or libs like lodash.

But, what if I don´t want to use systemJS or create JS-bundles everytime?
Is there another way?

Comment: Don't use imports if you don't want to, well, use imports. Use reference comments and internal modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you need a bundler or at least a loader. In time, browsers will directly support ES2015 modules. AFAIK, the only one that currently does is a recent Safari Developer Preview.

When they do, you'll load your main script as `type="module"`:

```
<script src="yourfile.js" type="module"></script>
```

...and within it any `import` statements like this:

```
import foo from "./foo.js";
```

...will be resolved and retrieved.

This is all proceeding very deliberatively, and things will change, but that's all we have in [the spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#attr-script-type) for now.

Comment: You´re right.. I can´t believe that no browser supports the ES2016 imports.. http://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-module

Comment: @derbronko: They will *very* soon, the initial minimal spec was only finalized fairly recently.